# get the term_id of current taxonomy page

Tags: plugin-development, taxonomy

I want to get the particular id of taxonomy in taxonomy page .I do this code as separate plugin file

i use this but it not give me the id of current taxonomy page and show this message
Notice: Trying to get property 'taxonomy' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\purevpn-website\purevpn-cms\wp-content\plugins\add-custom-schema-taxonomy\add-custom-schema-taxonomy.php on line 51

Notice: Trying to get property 'labels' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\purevpn-website\purevpn-cms\wp-content\plugins\add-custom-schema-taxonomy\add-custom-schema-taxonomy.php on line 52

Notice: Trying to get property 'singular_name' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\purevpn-website\purevpn-cms\wp-content\plugins\add-custom-schema-taxonomy\add-custom-schema-taxonomy.php on line 52

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
 $this_tax = get_taxonomy( $queried_object->taxonomy );
 echo $this_tax->labels->singular_name;
```

this is the code

Comment: What's the full code. If it runs on all pages it will throw an error whenever you're not on a taxonomy archive. Make sure you're checking `is_tax()` first.

Comment: The comment of Jacob is very good. You can also try to dumb your this_term variable to see if you get the object correctly.

Comment: now i change my code but still showing same warning